# Sending "click" Message to a Internet Explorer_Server window link

Tags: c++, winapi, sendmessage

Iam trying to automate a process in a little game which uses Internet Explorer_Server windows with  links as "buttons". 
I managed to get the handle of the window and also got the html code from it but now I struggle to send a "click" or Mousebuttonpressed event to the links. I would appreciate any help with this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot send mouse input directly to the inner controls of an IE window.  What you can do instead is start with the HWND of the "Internet Explorer_Server" window, ask it for its [`IHTMLDocument2`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752574.aspx) interface ([see here for details](https://web.archive.org/web/20130112011611/http://support.microsoft.com/kb/249232)), and then use Internet Explorer's own DOM interfaces to find the link elements as needed and call their `click()` method directly.

Comment: If you create the `CLSID_InternetExplorer` object directly, then you don't need to go hunting for it. The documentation for [IWebBrowser2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752127(v=VS.85).aspx) contains sample code.