# Find link elements of Internet Explorer_Server and send Click() event (C++)

Tags: c++, internet-explorer

i'm trying to programmatically send a click event to an  Internet Explorer_Server window of a program, I came across this question in StackOverflow that was simillar to my circumstance and followed its answer:
[Sending "click" Message to a Internet Explorer_Server window link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16242317/sending-click-message-to-a-internet-explorer-server-window-link)

Unfortunately i have a hard time figuring out how to find the right link elements and send a click() method for them.

I want to understand more in depth about what i'm working with here and what exactly is the Internet Explorer_Server window so i can search for the right answers and fourms on the way ahead.

Answer (score 1):

The "Internet Explorer" window is either a real Internet Explorer (the blue `e` on your desktop) or a hosted variant thereof. The core of Internet Explorer is "MSHTML.DLL" aka `IWebBrowser2` - an ActiveX control. Internet Explorer adds things like a window frame, favorites and other menu's to make a full web browser out of the ActiveX control. But pixelwise, 95% of Internet Explorer is just that single ActiveX control.

Comment: So in order to send a succesfull click event i'm supposed to use research how to detect buttons and send click event to an ActiveX control?

Comment: Yeah, pretty straightforward. `IWebBrowser` contains a document which contains the DOM which contains the buttons.